# Switch Windows 7 Pro to Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

While I was waiting to receive a new Windows 7 activation key for a system I was working on, I installed the anticipated version of Windows 7 (I converted my Windows 7 Ultimate disc into a flash drive that allows me to select which edition to install). I was anticipating I would receive a Windows 7 Professional license so I selected Professional when setting the system up, but I received a Windows 7 Ultimate license instead. That was a perfectly fine and pleasant surprise, but now I have a Windows 7 Professional installation and a Windows 7 Ultimate key. Is there any way to move my Pro installation up to Windows 7 Ultimate without having to reinstall the entire system? I've gotten everything arranged how I would like it, so I really hate reinstalling now. (When I search the web for how to move a system from Professional to Ultimate, the information seems focused on using pirated Ultimate licenses rather than moving to a legitimate Ultimate product key.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Windows Anytime upgrades were stopped in July 2016. This post now serves for historical purposes only.**

It's actually very easy. Just pop open your start menu, and search for "Windows Anytime Upgrade"

You'll see a program like this:

[image]

Once it is open, you will see two options here. One let's you buy a new version of Windows. The other is to add the upgrade key. All you have to do is click it, and insert the key

[image]

After you enter it, Windows will install a few features, and ask you to reboot. Tada! You will now be upgraded to Windows 7 Ultimate without touching your configuration.

Comment: If it's a full retail edition Ultimate key, it should work fine with Anytime Upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I should have tried that. I assumed an Anytime Upgrade key would be different from the normal key. I shall give it a whirl.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler its a surprisingly easy process! hopefully it works fine for you :)

Comment: Alas it did not, since I haven't yet activated the the system (it says I need to activate it before doing an Anytime Upgrade). Trouble is, I can't activate it since the system is set up as a "mere" Professional edition and the key is for Ultimate...

Comment: I believe you just need to activate windows then with a professional key before upgrading... If not, reinstall may be the only option..

Comment: Please be aware that Windows Anytime upgrades were stopped in July 2016

Comment: Interestingly, a comment-submitted-as-answer claims that an Anytime Upgrade worked just today. Did anything change?

Comment: And today again someone posted an answer claiming it works, though without being as explicit about _when_ it worked. (@Ben, bummer, Marc has not been seen here after posting that one answer/comment).